# Convertir una tabla en un JSON. Que sea dinámico para cualquier tabla

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
    <table id="" class="table table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md table-responsive-sm table-responsive-xs table-hover table-outline mb-0">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-dark">
         <th>
            <h4>Fecha</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Hora entrada</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Hora salida</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Descanso</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Horas laboradas</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Proyecto</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Observaciones</h4>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-01</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-02</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-03</td>
         <td>05:30 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>11:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-04</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-05</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-06</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-07</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-08</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sábado no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-09</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-10</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-11</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-12</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-13</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-14</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-15</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>01:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>06:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-16</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-17</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-18</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-19</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-20</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-21</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-22</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sábado no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-23</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-24</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>09:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>13:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-25</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-26</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>07:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>11:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-27</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-28</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>10:00 pm</td>
         <td>04:00</td>
         <td>11:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-29</td>
         <td>08:00 am</td>
         <td>11:30 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>03:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-30</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
            <h3>Total</h3>
         </td>
         <td colspan="3">
            <h3>221:30</h3>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <!---->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Ricardo ¿Cómo hizo usted para ordenar la tabla en bloques?

Comment: ha que se refiere usted?

Comment: Cuando yo publiqué esta pregunta el código de la tabla estaba todo desordenado y usted lo ordenó por bloques para hacerlo más legible, ¿cómo o hizo?

Comment: No recuerdo muy bien amigo, pero fue en una herramienta para indentar código por ejemplo: [Enlace](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar JQuery para hacer referencia a las cabeceras y registros de cada tabla, la siguiente función te puede ayudar:

```js
var myRows = [];
var $headers = $("th h4");
var $rows = $("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
  $cells = $(this).find("td");
  myRows[index] = {};
  $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
    myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
  });    
});

var myObj = {};
myObj.myrows = myRows;
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="" class="table table-responsive-lg table-responsive-md table-responsive-sm table-responsive-xs table-hover table-outline mb-0">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="bg-dark">
         <th>
            <h4>Fecha</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Hora entrada</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Hora salida</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Descanso</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Horas laboradas</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Proyecto</h4>
         </th>
         <th>
            <h4>Observaciones</h4>
         </th>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
   <tbody>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-01</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-02</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-03</td>
         <td>05:30 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>11:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-04</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-05</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-06</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-07</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-08</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sábado no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-09</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-10</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-11</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-12</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-13</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-14</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-15</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>01:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>06:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-16</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-17</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-18</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-19</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-20</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>00:30</td>
         <td>10:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-21</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>06:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>10:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-22</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sábado no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-23</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-24</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>09:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>13:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-25</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-26</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>07:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>11:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-27</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>05:00 pm</td>
         <td>01:00</td>
         <td>09:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-28</td>
         <td>07:00 am</td>
         <td>10:00 pm</td>
         <td>04:00</td>
         <td>11:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-29</td>
         <td>08:00 am</td>
         <td>11:30 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>03:30</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Sin obsevación</td>
      </tr>
      <tr style="cursor: pointer;">
         <td>2018-09-30</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>12:00 am</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>00:00</td>
         <td>Contrato 343/2017</td>
         <td>Dominical no laborado</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="4">
            <h4>Total</h4>
         </td>
         <td colspan="3">
            <h4>221:30</h4>
         </td>
      </tr>
      <!---->
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias muy buena esa función. Me gustaría saber por que o para que le coloca el signo $ a las variables como si fuese PHP.

Comment: Es JQuery, en este ejemplo se usó para hacer referencias a las partes de la tabla, puedes leer un poco su documentación y te será de mucha utilidad.

Comment: myRows[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).text()] = $(this).tex();
para eliminar las filas que tengan contendios h4 como en total!

Comment: Muchas gracias para lo que yo busco me sobran las últimas lineas, pero esta buena es función.